# Sending Telnet "DON'T" or "WON'T" after sending a "DO" or "WILL"

Tags: telnet

I apologize if this is off topic, not quite sure where else to ask.

I'm implementing my own Telnet library in Java (just because).  I'm wondering if my library should allow sending a "WONT" or "DONT" that was otherwise unsolicited.  I'm also wondering if my library should reply to unsolicited "DONT" or "WONT" requests with the "WONT" or "DONT" reply respectively.  The RFC isn't quite clear on that part of the contract.

All of this is assuming that I've already sent a DO and got a WILL, or visa versa.

Answer (score 0):

I think I realized the answer on my own:

If I receive a command that changes the state of an option, then I should acknowledge with the new state.  Defensive programming says I shouldn't expect an acknowledgement, but handle one cleanly.

If I disable an option changes my handling of the data stream, I shouldn't disable the processing until the byte after the response of  IAC DON'T/WON'T.